# Error 500 after keycloak authetication on gitlab

Tags: gitlab, keycloak, gitlab-omnibus

I configured keycloak with gitlab. I get routed to keycloak page but after passing the credentials getting error 500. I have wrecked my mind no clue what to look for.

```
gitlab_rails['omniauth_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['omniauth_block_auto_created_users'] = false
gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = ['oauth2_generic']
gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_sign_in_with_provider'] = 'oauth2_generic'
gitlab_workhorse['env'] = {
  'SSL_CERT_DIR' => '/etc/nginx/ssl'
}
gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [
{
        'name' => 'oauth2_generic',
        'app_id' => 'gitlab',
        'app_secret' => 'secret key',
        'args' => {
        client_options: {
                'site' => 'https://keycloak:8443', # including port if necessary
                'user_info_url' => '/auth/realms/Demo/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo',
                'authorize_url' => '/auth/realms/Demo/protocol/openid-connect/auth',
                'token_url' => '/auth/realms/Demo/protocol/openid-connect/token',
        },
        user_response_structure: {
        root_path: ['user'], # i.e. if attributes are returned in JsonAPI format (in a 'user' node nested under a 'data' node)
        attributes: { email:'email', first_name:'given_name', last_name:'family_name', name:'name', nickname:'preferred_username' }, # if the nickname attribute of a user is called 'username'
        id_path: 'preferred_username'
        },
        }
}
]
```

Comment: I found only one relevant log which is Faraday::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate))...
I already created self-signed certificate using the following..Not sure where I am going wrong here: